# Twitter API changes and client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

I have a browser extension (google chrome) that fetches and displays some public tweets, based on user input.

I've been using the [Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search) just fine, but according to the [API changes](https://dev.twitter.com/calendar), I have to migrate to API v1.1 where authenticated requests via oauth is required.

I have no previous experience with oauth, but it seems like a bad idea to implement it in pure client-side javascript, as the consumer key/secret will be exposed.

If I implement the authentication via a browser npapi/ppapi plugin, will it provide the needed security ? or does this mean that I have to dump this project and simply move on ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain an access token so that you can read data on behalf of your users. This involves implementing Twitter's 3-legged auth, which is very similar to implementing Twitter sign in (which thankfully is well documented).

The link below will take you to Twitter's overview of the differences between the two approaches to authenticating. From there you can get to the code samples that you'll need to implement this securely yourself.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/3-legged-authorization

Comment: This still doesn't solve the issue of exposing the consumer key/secret in the javascript file. Perhaps I'm missing something though.

Comment: This method involves exposing the consumer key but not the consumer secret. See example request on this page: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter

Comment: As far as I understand, I'll still need the consumer secret in order to sign the request, which still exposes the secret.